# ¿Qué metodo de ordenanza me recomiendan para java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, programación-funcional

Buenas, estoy estudiando Java en la universidad y nos han enseñado a utilizar fábricas de comparadores. Pero mirando en internet he descubierto que te ahorras bastantes líneas de código utilizando expresiones lambda.

He conseguido ordenar una lista de objetos (diferentes pero de una misma clase padre) de las siguientes maneras:

- `Collections.sort(listaFiguras, Comparator.comparing(Figura::getArea));`
- `listaFiguras = listaFiguras.stream().sorted((e1, e2) -> Float.compare(e1.getArea(), e2.getArea())).collect(Collectors.toList());`

¿Cuál me recomiendan?

O por el contrario... ¿me recomiendan crear la fábrica de comparadores?

Comment: Publica el codigo del metodo getArea para poder dar una respuesta completa.

Comment: Técnicamente, la primera opción es la más eficiente, porque no necesita crear mas objetos.

Comment: Gracias por responder, el código de getArea() es simplemente un getter que devuelve un float.